# JSONP convert function in Simile 3.0

Tags: jsonp, simile

I'm using Simile to display some data. I have a JSONP file which I have to format correctly before using it. Using JSONP example from Exhibit website I have been able to do so using 2.2 version of the Exhibit API:

```
<link rel="exhibit/data" type="application/jsonp"
    href="http://www.editgrid.com/user/ecmanaut/font-names.exhibit.jsonp"
    ex:jsonp-callback="editgridCallback" ex:converter="fontConverter" />
```

I want to update my code to exhibit 3.0 and I am using the following code:

```
<link rel="exhibit/data" type="application/jsonp"
  href="http://www.editgrid.com/user/ecmanaut/font-names.exhibit.jsonp"
  data-ex-jsonp-callback="cbfunc" data-ex-converter="fontConverter" />
```

But fontConverter function does not execute. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: data-ex-jsonp-callback might be deprecated. Try href="...exhibit.php?callback=cbfunc" without the data-ex-jsonp-callback parameter.